# Convert array of tuples into 2d array

Tags: f#

I just wonder is there a better approach to convert an array of tuples into a two-dimensional array?

```
let list = [|("a", "1"); ("b", "2"); ("c", "3")|];;
let arr = Array2D.init (Array.length list) 2 (fun i j -> if j <> 0 then (fst list.[i]) else (snd list.[i]));;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more concise way is to use [array2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620670.aspx):

```
[|("a", "1"); ("b", "2"); ("c", "3")|]
|> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> [|x; y|])
|> array2D
```

But is there any reason why you don't use an array of arrays from beginning for easy initialization e.g.

```
let arr =
  [|[|"a"; "1"|]; 
    [|"b"; "2"|]; 
    [|"c"; "3"|]|]
  |> array2D
```

Comment: I'm receiving a list of tuples from a function which I cannot really change

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @pad that the easiest option is to use `array2D` function. I generally prefer to use sequence expressions over higher-order functions (like `Seq.map`), so I would probably write:

```
let arr =
  array2D [ for char, num in list ->
              [ char; num ] ]
```

This does essentially the same thing as the answer from @pad. It creates a list of lists, which is a data structure expected by `array2D` (it would be more efficient to write the outer as `seq { .. }`, but I used lists for simplicity).